# UDP sendto() error: invalid argument

Tags: c, udp

We are trying to apply a UDP based protocol and having some problem with sendto() function.

when we try to response to the write-request with ack we get "invalid argument" from the sendto() function

this is our code:

```
int                sock;                  // Socket 
sockaddr_in_t      echoServAddr;          // Local address 
sockaddr_in_t      echoClntAddr;          // Client address 
unsigned int       cliAddrLen;            // Length of incoming message
data_packet_t      echoBuffer;
wrq_packet_t       wrqBuffer;
unsigned short     echoServPort;          // Server port 
int                recvMsgSize;           // Size of received message 
ack_packet_t      Ack;
struct timeval     timeout;
fd_set             fds;



/* Create socket for sending/receiving datagrams */
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) perror("TTFTPERROR: socket() failed"); 

/* Construct local address structure */
memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));
echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort);

/*Bind to the local address */
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0) perror("TTFTPERROR: bind() failed");

FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(sock, &fds);
timeout.tv_sec = WAIT_FOR_PACKET_TIMEOUT;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

while (1) {
    recvMsgSize = recvfrom(sock, &wrqBuffer, FULL_PACKET_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, &cliAddrLen);
    if (recvMsgSize > 0) break; // we got something!
}

Ack = CreateAckPacket(0); // send ack 0
if (sendto(sock, &Ack, sizeof(Ack), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, sizeof(echoClntAddr)) == -1){
    perror("TTFTPERROR: sendto() failed to send ack 0");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Could you help us understand what is wrong?

Comment: what is the error/error code?

Comment: 22, The error is "invalid argument"

Comment: @szczurcio: That would be a compiler error, not a runtime error. But the [`sendto()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html) that I know takes a `const void *` as second argument.

Comment: @MartinR I thought the OP meant a compiler error, I guess it should be clarified in the question. And well, it depends on the environment, the Windows API takes a `const char*`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: compilation pass perfectly though, and the error is recieved when we run the program, do you suggest that I'll cast the `Ack` variable to `const char *` ? , akthough I've searched online and so some examples that use sendoto() as we did...

Comment: @user3350919 You are compiling with `-Wall`, right? This should give you at least a warning.

Answer (score 11):

The likely error is a combination of the `sendto` line and `recvfrom` a few lines above.

What you are doing is, you reuse the sockaddr that `recvfrom` gave you to send a reply (ACK in this case). That is absolutely legitimate and correct, how else could you send a reply to someone on a connectionless protocol (you have no other way of knowing whom to send the answer to, nor with what protocol version!).

**But:** While you *correctly* provide `&cliAddrLen` to `recvfrom` so it can return the actual address length (which may vary, think of IPv4 vs IPv6 addresses) that was written into the buffer `echoClntAddr`, you later call `sendto` with `sizeof(echoClntAddr)` as the size of the address field.
Since `echoClntAddr` is most likely a `sockaddr_storage` (it should be, anyway), its size will be larger than any valid protocol's address size. Thus, it's an invalid argument. Or rather, the address is.

You should instead call `sendto` with `cliAddrLen` (and initialize `cliAddrLen` to  `sizeof(echoClntAddr)` prior to calling `recvfrom`).

Answer (score 2):

Also be very careful to you pass VALID and EXISTING IP address to the bind()'s parameter:
echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr

If you don't have network interface exposed with that exactly IP address the bind won't fail on some platforms (ESP32 for example) BUT the sendto() WILL definitely fail. I've spend 2 days debugging that and I'm mad!