# sendto dest_len not valid

Tags: c, udp, errno

I am working on a UDP server, and I am getting a an errno of `EINVAL` from the `sendto` function. The documentation says that this is because `The dest_len argument is not a valid length for the address family`. I cannot make sense of this. Here is the offending line.

```
*clientlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
printf("Clientlen: %d\n",*clientlen);
perror("Before:");
tmpn = sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) clientaddr, *clientlen);
perror("After:");
printf("Errno: %d\n",errno);
if(tmpn < 0) perror("Acknowledging");
printf("Clientlen: %d\n",*clientlen);
```

This gives this information:

```
Clientlen: 16
Before:: Success
After:: Invalid argument
Errno: 22
Acknowledging: Invalid argument
Clientlen: 16
```

This is the documentation to which I am referring: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html

I know that perror is set in this line so the issue must be coming from here. The value of `clientlen` is `16`, and I am using `ipv4` and `udp`.

I looked through this question, but it doesn't seem to help.
[UDP sendto() error: invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941151/udp-sendto-error-invalid-argument)

As a desparate hope I tried all even integers from 0 to 32 (specifically 28 and 16, ipv4 and ipv6 respectively) to see if that fixed the issue, and it did not. I would love suggestions.

Comment: This code doesn't test `tmpn` or call `perror()`. How do you know there was an error at all, let alone what it was?

Comment: I went through rounds of testing `perror()` and the `tmpn` test was after this bit of code.

Comment: This bit of code has already corrupted `errno` by calling `printf()`. You have to call `perror()` before making any other system calls. Edit confirms it. NB It is not correct to call `perror()` unless there *was* an error.

Comment: @EJP These are all things I had already checked, and then gone through multiple other versions to check all possibilities I could think of.

Comment: Your edit proves my point. The code is not valid. Fix it, re-run it, and tell us what the error really was.

Comment: @EJP I just ran this again. There's the exact code and the exact output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155176/discussion-between-hovestar-and-ejp).

Comment: is your `buf[]` really BUFSIZE bytes?

Comment: @user3629249 it is defined to be `char buf[BUFSIZE];`